Is there a way to configure an Xcode project to use a different toolchain?
I have an Xcode project that requires building with a different toolchain than the normal one included with Xcode. I can select this toolchain from the Xcode > Toolchains menu, but that changes the toolchain for all of Xcode and any open project. Rather than having to remember to change this setting around as I switch between projects, is there any way I can configure this one project to use the toolchain it requires?
